# overloading cout ostream operator in C++

Tags: c++, cout, ostream

I have a question about printing template class in c++ programing. Using Point2D class, I want to print out the template class mylist as auto x:mylist, but I keep failing.

Is there any way to solve this problem without touching any classes and using Point2D print function by ostream operator << ? (auto x:mylist is mandatory)

The answer should in the form if you enter two integers, then save it as Point2D, and print is as if Point2D (2,3), lastly, it should print out multiple Point2Ds without (-1,-1).

For example, if I enter 2\n 3\n 5\n 6\n -1\n -1\n, then the answer should be in the form of ((2,3),(5,6)) <-not including (-1,-1)

Please Help me!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <conio.h>

//declaration for Node, Iterator class;
template <class T>
class Node;
template <class T>
class Iterator;
class Point2D;

template <class T>
class List{
public:
    //constructor and destructor
    List();
    ~List();
    //list begin & end
    Iterator<T> begin();
    Iterator<T> end();
private:
    Node<T>* first;
    Node<T>* last;
    int size;

   friend class Iterator<T>;
   friend class Point2D;
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const List<T>& list);
};

 template <class T>
 class Iterator{
 public:
    Iterator();
    T operator*() const;
    Iterator<T>& operator++();
    Iterator<T> operator++(int unused);
    Iterator<T>& operator--();
    Iterator<T> operator--(int unused);
    bool operator ==(Iterator<T> b)const;
    bool operator!=(Iterator<T> b)const;
private:
    Node<T>* position;
    List<T>* container;
//declare the List as friend
friend class List<T>;
 };

class Point2D {
public:
     // Constructors
    Point2D();
    Point2D(double a, double b);
    // Print functions
    virtual void print();
private:
    double x;
    double y;
};


template <class T>
List<T>::List(){
     //initialization
     first=NULL;
     last=NULL;
    size=0; 
 }

 template <class T>
 List<T>::~List(){
    delete first;
    delete last;
    delete size;
 }

//check begin()
template <class T>
Iterator<T> List<T>::begin(){
    Iterator<T> iter;
    iter.position=first;
    iter.container=this;
    return iter;
 }

//check end()
template <class T>
Iterator<T> List<T>::end(){
    Iterator<T> iter;
    iter.position=NULL;
    iter.container=this;
    return iter;
 }

 //check begin()
 template <class T>
 Iterator<T> List<T>::begin(){
     Iterator<T> iter;
     iter.position=first;
     iter.container=this;
     return iter;
 }
 //check end()
 template <class T>
 Iterator<T> List<T>::end(){
    Iterator<T> iter;
    iter.position=NULL;
    iter.container=this;
    return iter;
 }

 //Iterator operator * -> pointing the position
 template <class T>
 T Iterator<T>::operator*()const
  {
      assert(position !=NULL);
      return position->data;
  }

 //pre increment for operator++
 template <class T>
      Iterator<T>& Iterator<T>::operator++() {
      assert(position!=NULL);
      position=position->next;
      return* this;
 }
 //post increment for operator++
 template <class T>
 Iterator<T> Iterator<T>::operator++(int unused) {
    assert(position != NULL);
    auto clone(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return clone;
 }
 //pre increment for operator--
 template <class T>
 Iterator<T>& Iterator<T>::operator--() {
      assert(position!=container->first);
      if(position==NULL) position =container->last;
      else position=position->previous;
      return* this;
 }
 //post increment for operator--
 template <class T>
 Iterator<T> Iterator<T>::operator --(int unused){
     auto clone(*this);
         --(*this);
         return clone;
 } 
 //boolean operator to check ==
 template <class T>
 bool Iterator<T>::operator ==(Iterator<T> b)const{
 return position==b.position;
 }
 //boolean operator to check !=
 template <class T>
 bool Iterator<T>::operator!=(Iterator<T> b)const{
    return position!=b.position;
 }

 Point2D::Point2D() { x = 0; y = 0; return; }
 Point2D::Point2D(double a, double b) { x = a; y = b; return; }

 void Point2D::print() {
    std::cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
    return;
 }

int main(){
 List<Point2D> mylist;
Iterator<Point2D> myiterator = mylist.begin();
std::cout << "Please input a set of nonnegative numbers for a list";
std::cout << " (Enter -1 when you are finished): " << std::endl;

//if select1 &2=-1 stop the loop
while (select1 != -1&&select2 !=-1)
{
    std::cin >> select1;
    std::cin >> select2;
    /*since data is nonnegative set store the data if it is greater than 
      using push_back function*/
    if (select1>0||select2>0)
    mylist.push_back(Point2D(select1,select2));
}
//printing the mylist followed by given format;
std::cout << "Your list is"<<std::endl<<"(";
for (auto x:mylist)
std::cout << x << ",";
std::cout <<'\b'<< ")"<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always write an ostream operator outside of all the classes:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Point2D p) {
   p.print(); 
   return os; 
}
```

You can then call it by doing `cout<< p<<endl`;

The problem in your case, is that `print()` is specific to the output stream, whereas `<<` is independent of the `ostream`.  In consequence, the latter could be used for string streams or file streams, with a wrong implementeation,  so that if one day, you try to output to a file instead of to the console  this code would continue to print on the console leaving the expected output destination  empty.

It would be VERY VERY advisable to change your print(), so to use an ostream:

```
virtual void print(ostream& os);
```

Comment: Great!! This is what I was looking for thank you for your help